# How do I save and change the value of a variable in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, variable-assignment, mutation

This may be a very newbie question, but I didn't find the answer.
I need to store, for example a list and later replace it with another, under the same pointer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be done via [*references*](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual003.html#toc8):

```
let fact n =
  let result = ref 1 in (* initialize an int ref *)
  for i = 2 to n do
    result := i * !result (* reassign an int ref *)
   done;
  !result
```

You do not see references very often because you can do the same thing using immutable values inside recursion or high-order functions:

```
let fact n =
   let rec loop i acc =
      if i > n then acc
      else loop (i+1) (i*acc) in
   loop 2 1
```

Side-effect free solutions are preferred since they are easier to reason about and easier to ensure correctness.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me the meaning of ref 0 ?

Comment: See the link I refer to in my answer. Basically `ref 0` is a record `{mutable contents: int}` with `contents` initialized by `0` and `contents` could be reassigned later.